# Landau levels in 2D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons, schroedinger-equation

I seem to be having a very basic misunderstanding of Landau levels in 2D. Consider the derivation give on page 7 [here](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~pjh/teaching/phy4605/notes/landau.pdf), where we consider electrons free to move in 2 dimensions, with a magnetic field applied perpendicular to the plane. The wave function they get is

$\psi(x,y)=\exp(ik_y y)u_n(x-x_0)$

In particular, if you square this to get the probability density, you get

$|\psi|^2(x,y)=u_n^2(x-x_0)$ which does not depend on $y$. This makes no sense at all to me. Any sort of illustration I can find of this shows localized electron orbits around points in the x-y plane, analogous to the orbits of classical charged particles in a magnetic field.

How can the probability density possibly be independent of $y$?

Comment: Why is that so shocking? Note that not all eigenstates are of that form (you're just focusing on one specific set of states) and that your choice of gauge already broke the symmetry between $x$ and $y$. In particular, in that gauge the hamiltonian is translationally invariant along $y$ - so why is it surprising that its eigentstates share that property?

Comment: Because if I choose a different gauge that gives the same magnetic field, I can get harmonic oscillators in both x and y, and the eigenstates are completely different. Since the magnetic field is the same in both cases, shouldn't the resulting physics be the same?

Also here (http://uw.physics.wisc.edu/~himpsel/551/Lectures/Landau.pdf) they go through the same derivation, but then plot the probability density and show localization in both x and y. How can that wavefunction be reconciled with the pictures on slide 6?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty also what do you mean by not all eigenstates being of that form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is hinted at in the bottom 3 lines of Slide 5 in your 2nd ref., http://uw.physics.wisc.edu/~himpsel/551/Lectures/Landau.pdf:

> "The same B-field can be created by other vector potentials, such as $A = \frac{1}{2} (-B_z y , B_z x , 0)$. This ambiguity is called gauge symmetry."

In other words, Landau's gauge for the magnetic field is most effective for deriving a simple separable solution, but not the most relevant one for the problem's symmetry to rotations around the $z$-axis.

In Landau's gauge the solution to the localization problem is to note that the harmonic energy levels are strongly degenerate due to their dependence on $k_y$. This degeneracy allows, in principle, the construction of states localized along both $x$ and $y$. As a side note, the same kind of result would be obtained on interchanging the $x$ and $y$ directions. We'd get degenerate plane waves along $x$ and a harmonic oscillator along $y$, and we'd have to construct states localized along $x$.

But a more elegant approach is to observe that we can choose a symmetric gauge from the beginning, reading, as pointed out in the quote, $A = \frac{1}{2} (-B_z y , B_z x , 0)$. In this case the solution is somewhat more complicated to arrive at, but produces the expected explicitly symmetric eigenstates, with harmonic oscillator energy eigenvalues and a degeneracy indexed this time by the system's angular momentum along $z$.

See an outline on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization#Landau_Levels_in_Symmetric_Gauge), or in these [notes](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/landau.pdf), or in polar coordinates [here](http://ramen.physics.und.edu/~yloh/TEACHING/PHYS536/N3-LandauLevels.nb.pdf), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm curious though - how is it possible to construct a function with y dependence from eigenfunctions that only have x dependence?

Comment: It's not the wave function $\psi(x,y)$ that has only x dependence, it's the probability $|\psi(x,y)|^2$. A superposition of plane waves along $y$ can produce a y-localized wave function through interference. For instance a harmonic oscillator wave function can always be represented as a plane wave superposition, the coefficients being the oscillator wave function in momentum representation: $\psi_n(x) \equiv \langle x|\psi_n\rangle = \int{dp \langle x|p\rangle \langle p | \psi_n\rangle } = \int{dp e^{-ipx/\hbar}\psi_n( p)}$.